# Create a function/macro in R which can loop over different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have created like ten different data frames (eg. df1, df2, ..., df10). I want to use the function `spread` in R on all these data frames. My solution is to create a function in R that can repeat the function `spread` on all the data frames and create ten new data frames with the updated name: `df1_wide`, `df2_wide`, ..., `df10_wide`.
My initial idea is something like this:

```
new_function <- function(df) {
"df"_wide <- spread(df, key=time, value=values)
}

df_list <- list(df1,df2,...,df10)

function(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spread` has been retired so you may switch to `pivot_wider`. Use `lapply` to apply the custom function to each dataframe in the list.

```
new_function <- function(df) {
  tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from =time, values_from =values)
}

df_list <- list(df1,df2,...,df10)
#Or
#df_list <- mget(paste0('df', 1:10))

df_result <- lapply(df_list, new_function)
```